# How can I see the xltrail-generated diff of an Excel workbook in Beyond Compare?

Tags: excel, git, diff, beyondcompare4

I'm using Git for Windows with the [xltrail extension](https://www.xltrail.com/client) to provide a readable output when using `git diff <Excel workbook>`.  I'm also using the graphical diff/merge tool [Beyond Compare 4 Pro](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) which runs when using `git difftool` and provides a nice side-by-side diff and three-way merge interface.

However, when I run `git difftool <Excel workbook>`, I get the normal `git diff` output without a prompt to open Beyond Compare.  How can I get Git, xltrail, and Beyond Compare to work together?

## Edit #1

Here's a complete example of this not working:

```
$ git config diff.tool; git config difftool.bc.path; git config difftool.prompt
bc
c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
false


$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[diff "xltrail"]
        command = git-xltrail-diff.exe
[merge "xltrail"]
        name = xltrail merge driver for Excel workbooks
        driver = git-xltrail-merge.exe %P %O %A %B


$ cat ~/.gitconfig
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.

[user]
        name = Andrew Keeton
        email = AKeeton@example.com

[push]
        default = simple

[alias]
        co  = checkout
        ci  = commit
        cam = commit -am
        st  = status
        br  = branch

        # short log
        shlog = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow bold)%h%Creset %ad %C(cyan)|%Creset %s%C(magenta)%d%Creset %C(bold)[%an]%Creset\" --date=short --name-only
        hist  = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow bold)%h%Creset %ad %C(cyan)|%Creset %s%C(magenta)%d%Creset %C(bold)[%an]%Creset\" --date=short --graph

[diff]
        tool = bc

[difftool "bc"]
        path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe

[difftool]
        prompt = false


$ git st
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   workbook.xlsm
        modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


$ git diff README.md
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index a052e20..3fd700d 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -40,6 +40,11 @@

 ## Tips

+* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
+* Curabitur a dui eu massa feugiat varius tempor eget tellus.
+* Nullam et fringilla eros.
+* Etiam euismod ipsum enim, non molestie nunc varius eu.
+
 * In Excel, press `CTRL+G` to open the *Go To* window.  This makes it easy to find the various tables and "anchors."

 ## xltrail


$ git difftool README.md
<See screenshot of README.md in Beyond Compare 4>


$ git diff workbook.xlsm
diff --xltrail a/workbook.xlsm b/workbook.xlsm
--- a/workbook.xlsm/VBA/Module/modWorksheet
+++ b/workbook.xlsm/VBA/Module/modWorksheet
@@ -14,6 +14,7 @@
     Dim dDouble1 As Double
     Dim dDouble2 As Double
     Dim dDouble3 As Double
+    Dim sString1 As String
     Dim dDouble4 As Double

     Dim iInteger1 As Integer



$ git difftool workbook.xlsm
diff --xltrail a/workbook.xlsm b/workbook.xlsm
--- a/workbook.xlsm/VBA/Module/modWorksheet
+++ b/workbook.xlsm/VBA/Module/modWorksheet
@@ -14,6 +14,7 @@
     Dim dDouble1 As Double
     Dim dDouble2 As Double
     Dim dDouble3 As Double
+    Dim sString1 As String
     Dim dDouble4 As Double

     Dim iInteger1 As Integer
```

### Screenshot of README.md in Beyond Compare 4

[image: Screenshot of README.md in Beyond Compare 4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Complete Solution (added by question-asker)

Create an executable script `xltrail-bc-diff.sh` in the existing `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git xltrail\` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# xltrail-bc-diff.sh massages the output of git-xltrail-diff.exe and passes it
# into Beyond Compare in "Text Patch" mode.
#
# Input arguments from `git diff` are:
#    $1   $2       $3      $4       $5       $6      $7
#    path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

path="$1"
tempDiffPath=`mktemp --suffix=".diff"`

# xltrail's diff output is color-coded with no option to remove it
# (see https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/git-xltrail/issues/30) so we use
# sed to strip the color codes.
git-xltrail-diff.exe $@ | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > $tempDiffPath

BCompare.exe -fv="Text Patch" $tempDiffPath
```

Add the following to your git config file:

```
[diff "xltrail-bc"]
    command = xltrail-bc-diff.sh
```

In the repository there should be a `.gitattributes` file that was created by xltrail to associate Excel files with the xltrail diff and merge tools.  Change the diff entries to use `xltrail-bc`:

```
*.xla diff=xltrail-bc
*.xlam diff=xltrail-bc
*.xls diff=xltrail-bc
*.xlsb diff=xltrail-bc
*.xlsm diff=xltrail-bc
*.xlsx diff=xltrail-bc
*.xlt diff=xltrail-bc
*.xltm diff=xltrail-bc
*.xltx diff=xltrail-bc
```

And now `git diff <Excel workbook>` should open up in Beyond Compare.

---

## Original Answer

First, you need to setup your git with something like that:

```
git config --global diff.tool bc4
git config --global difftool.bc4.cmd "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BCompare.exe\" \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Then, you can check/edit your **.git/config** file, and ensure having something like that:

```
[diff]
tool = bc4
```

If it is not enough, please post your **.git/config** file.

Edit, for further needs.
It seems it not basically possible to plug xtrail and Beyond Compare like that.
I reproduced your issue with success.
I though something may be possible to be done in the .gitattributes file, but without success.

So ... the only possible solution, complex one, will be to create your own diff script, and to plug all tools together.

On my side, I tried with a GNU/Bash script (you can get it supported installing Git Bash on your Windows), but you may want to create a .bat one.

First, you need to update your **.git/config** configuration file, to specify the path to your new script file, for instance:

```
[diff "myComplexDiff"]
    command = C:/Users/XXX/Documents/complexGitDiff.sh
```

Then, you need to link file extension with this diff, updating your **.gitattributes** file, with something like (to ba adpated for any wanted extension ):

```
*.xls diff=myComplexDiff
```

And then, the script, which can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# Sample of information given by git
# b851185776b7826a6cc82d3aa6a8d53fa47e0c26 100644 simpleTest.xls 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100644
fileName="$1"
tmpFile="/tmp/"$( date +'%s')"$fileName.diff"
git-xltrail-diff.exe $@ >"$tmpFile"
c:\\Program\ Files\\Beyond\ Compare\ 4\\bcomp.exe "$fileName" "$tmpFile"
```

Actually I didn't find the needed option for Beyond Compare to accept the diff output of git-xltrail-diff.exe, but it is the only remaining thing to do.

Comment: I already have `git difftool` set up similarly (but with prompting on) so that when I do `git difftool README.md` I get `Viewing (1/1): 'README.md'\n Launch 'bc' [Y/n]?` and then it opens Beyond Compare with the proper side-by-side diff.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the relevant sections of my .gitconfig: https://pastebin.com/GpRcpSsQ

Comment: Like you can see the **prompt=false** is missing in your config file. Maybe there is a mix with you global git configuration and your local repository configuration? Try to add it again. It should work with git config, otherwise you can add it manually in your config file.

Comment: I changed `prompt` to `false` but I don't think that would matter.  See **Edit #1** in my original post.

Comment: I edited my answer with a new complex solution ;)  Let me know if you need further helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I hijacked the top of your answer with my complete solution so that others in need see it first.

Comment: Nice it solves your issue. Nevertheless, I would recommend not using the C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git xltrail\ path, but instead a specific path of yours, where you could keep your own script, and either update your **%PATH%** environment variable, either adapt your git configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, this also works with [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) which is free unlike BeyondCompare.

Just make sure to upgrade to the latest version of SourceTree while [git-xltrail](https://www.xltrail.com/client) is installed and activated. You don't even have to change any settings, it should just work.

For details, see my blog post here: https://dev.to/fzumstein/how-to-diff-excel-vba-code-in-sourcetree-git-client-36k